# Why doesn't postgres throw error when no join predicate is given in the FROM clause of an UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

For example in the following query:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.a = b.id
FROM (SELECT * FROM B) b;
```

This query doesn't throw any error.
What does the FROM do in this case.
Does it do a cross product between A and B, Then pick some random entry from B?
When i do explain i don't see any join, When i add a join predicate in where then there's a hash join. But not in this case.

Just curious about the functioning, Don't plan on using this query.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error because it's _syntactically_ correct. The syntax checker doesn't check semantics. It doesn't throw an error on `select * from a,b` either or `select * from a join b on true`

Comment: It doesn't throw even when i run it. Am just wondering if a random id from b will be assigned to a. and after checking i see that that's what is happening. I understood that the join is the same as the first query u mentioned, `select * from A,B`, Then update happens on which ever row comes first from B.

Comment: It will generate a cross join and will update all rows from that - so a row in `A` will be updated multiple times with the same value

Comment: Oh, Got it, So Each row in A is updated |B| times. So the update happens as if its happening on the resultant join.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is in fact an update join, according to Postgres syntax, but it is lacking a `WHERE` clause which would provide the join condition between the two tables.  Most likely, you intended to use something along these lines:

```
UPDATE A a
SET A.a = b.id
FROM B b
WHERE a.pk = b.fk;     -- join condition is here
```

As it stands now, every record in the `A` table would be joined to every record in the `B` table, so the update logic is not well defined.

Comment: I was just curious about the functioning, this is not a query i was planning to use. So postgres does a cross product and during update it picks one row from B? is that what will happen?

Comment: @AdithyaSama To be honest, I've never even thought about what would happen during an update cross join.  I suppose that only one value assignment would "stick" in the end, so what that value ends up being might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your table and `subquery` doesn't have any reference row which to update. So this will pickup the first row in `B`.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.a = b.id
FROM (SELECT * FROM B) b;
```

For your question, why this is working, is it because `b = SELECT * FROM B`, `subqueries` can function as result table.